# check valid email and email domain in PHP

Tags: php, email-validation, email-address

i want to see if lazar@hotmail.com23 is valid (it isnt) in the PHP code here:

```
 // Remove all illegal characters from email
            $Buyer_Email = filter_var($Buyer_Email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

            // Validate e-mail
            if (filter_var($Buyer_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('/@.+\./', $Buyer_Email) === false) {
```

but the code says its valid.

i checked online and i cant seem to figure out whats wrong

Whats wrong?

Comment: Which part of your if statement is coming back true? The filter-var or the preg_match?

Comment: Technicaly, it is valid if checked by a regexp. If you want more comprehensive validation you could use DNS lookup of some sort. Something like this : https://davidwalsh.name/php-email-validator

Comment: i am assuming preg_match and this helps M de Lormier ill look into it!

Comment: why both with the preg_match at all? just use the `filter_var`